# Is it possible to use impersonated access token within non-interactive session to get new access token to other Audience in Azure Active Directory?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

Actors:

1. Black box (MS Power App custom connector) with user logged in
2. API A - .NET Standard WebApi with [Authorize] attribute and AAD authorization enabled (no additional verification in code), ida:audience="A" in web.config
3. API B - .NET Standard WebApi with [Authorize] attribute and AAD authorization enabled (no additional verification in code), ida:audience="B" in web.config
4. API C - .NET Standard WebApi with [Authorize] attribute and AAD authorization enabled (no additional verification in code), ida:audience="C" in web.config

Flow:
Power App connector calls API A. Within the code of API A (C#) I can decode JWT from Authorization header and see which user is logged in. Now, I have to call API B and API C and then return something to Power App connector. API B and API C must be able to also decode JWT and get UPN from token.

Problem:
When I tried to reuse whole Authorization header (just get it within API A and add to HttpClient to call API B and C) I get 401.
Now I know that was because of ida:Audience value. I suppose it is part of .NET framework verification, beyond my control. When I changed ida:Audience in API B and C to "A" it worked. But it was only for testing purposes, I am not allowed to do it in production.
Then I tried to set scopes in Power App connector to multiple values (delimited by space) with different audiences - no luck, error from AAD, multiple audiences not allowed.

So, my question is: is it possible in my scenario to do what I need? I have only access token for audience A and have to authorize (with impersonation) in endpoints with other audience value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what the *on-behalf-of* flow is for.
It allows API A to take the access token it received and ask for an access token to API B (with the same user info in the token).
More info on the flow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow.

Example request content from documentation to token endpoint that uses a client secret:

```
//line breaks for legibility only

POST /oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant>
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer
client_id=535fb089-9ff3-47b6-9bfb-4f1264799865
&client_secret=sampleCredentia1s
&assertion=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6InowMzl6ZHNGdWl6cEJmQlZLMVRuMjVRSFlPMCJ9.eyJhdWQiOiIyO{a lot of characters here}
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read+offline_access
&requested_token_use=on_behalf_of
```

Using MSAL.NET is definitely better than using the HTTP endpoint directly though.
You would replace the `scope` in this request with a scope from API B.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. From AAD i get "AADSTS500131: Assertion audience does not match the Client app presenting the assertion. The audience in the assertion was 'A' and the expected audience is '<client guid>' or one of the Application Uris of this application with App ID '<client guid>'(<client name>). The downstream client must request a token for the expected audience (the application that made the OBO request) and this application should use that token as the assertion.". Scope in OBO request belongs to audience B.

Comment: Sounds like the "assertion" i.e. the token you received has an audience that does not match that app. Check that the token audience matches the app identified by client_id.

Comment: I used wrong client id. Finally it works. Thank you.